# How to expand all mat-expansion-panel with complex array by click a button?

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, mat-expansion-panel

I am trying to display Mat-expansion-panel by click "open all" button. Now, i face the problem is inner panel is not working. It only can open the outside  only. I would like to open all panel with inner panel. How to achieve it ?  Please help.
[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fyvrbd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to expand expansion panels, but you are selecting accordion, this is the problem with your code, what you can do is use [viewchildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) , select all expansion panels, and then open them when you want. here is how the code will look like

```
  @ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) panels: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;


openAll(){
this.panels.forEach(panel => panel.open();)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all expansion panel instance using ViewChildren decorator

```
@ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) expansionPanel: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

Then call open method on it when you click openAll button

```
openll() {
    this.expansionPanel.toArray().forEach((panel)=>{
      panel.open();
    })
}
```

**[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ocawkf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**